# Migrating Uno (UWP) application to WinUI 3.0

Tags: datagrid, uno-platform, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3, uniformgrid

I have an UWP based uno app with Droid, iOS, wasm. I would like to update it to a WinUI 3 based app, and delete the UWP platform.

In my project Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls is used, because of UniformGrid and DataGrid.
I want to change Uno.UI to Uno.WinUI according to this article: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/updating-to-winui3.html
but the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls depends on the Uno.UI.

How can I use DataGrid and UniformGrid in the new WinUI 3 desktop app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

WCT (Windows Community Toolkit) packages are published under a different name for WinUI: they are named [`CommunityToolkit.WinUI.*`](https://nuget.info/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI) instead of [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.*`](https://nuget.info/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp).

As of writing this response, this branch of WCT has not been ported to Uno yet. No migration strategy for this specific toolkit has been announced yet.